# Pass this and string as parameter in jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to append this following tag which has an `onclick` function.

```
 $("body").append('<img onclick="removeDynamicColumn(this,'someString')" src="css/images/builder/removeTDTR.png"/>');
```

In this function I am passing two parameters one is, the element itself and another one is string , if I enclose that string parameter with single quotes in JSP itself showing this error -

> Syntax error on token "someString", invalid AssignmentOperator.

If I enclose with double quotes while calling that function I got this error -

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Missing Escape '\' character in your code.

Try that code;

```
$("body").append('<img onclick="removeDynamicColumn(this,\'someString\')" src="css/images/builder/removeTDTR.png"/>');
```

Comment: To add to this. The reason it wasn't working was because you weren't escaping the sting by using \

Answer (score 4):

Try escape \

```
 $("body").append('<img onclick="removeDynamicColumn(this,\'someString\')" src="css/images/builder/removeTDTR.png"/>');
```

Answer (score 3):

let's assume we have an string in a variable like this:

```
var param = "somestring"
```

we can inject this variable to your example, this way:

```
$("body").append('<img onclick="removeDynamicColumn(this, \'' + param + '\')" src="css/images/builder/removeTDTR.png"/>');
```

G.L

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape your quote marks.

Try using `\` before the `'` characters around `someString`.

`\'someString\'`

Answer (score 2):

Why bind it like that - if you are using jQuery then you can use a [delegated bind](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) and then use `data-` attributes for your string:

```js
var body = $("body");

// give your image a class and data attribute for your string
body.append('<img src="css/images/builder/removeTDTR.png" data-string="some string" class="click-image">')

// this is delegated bind
body.on('click', '.click-image', function() {
   var image = $(this),                  // your image as a jquery object
       someString = image.data('string'); // your string 
   // do your onclick action here
});
```

Comment: thanks pete for ur suggestion, actually the above mentioned is sample program, actually I append this tag to an <td> of an html table, that itself I creating rows and column dynamically...

Comment: So in my code, your append would stay where it is and the new bind  would be put into the document ready - a delegated bind is all about dynamically created elements - have a read of the link I have provided, it would be a better way of doing things in my opinion